# how to merge branches after Git revert

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, branching-and-merging, git-revert

the story so far - project repository has among others two branches - `update` and `master`. There was a a try to merge `update` into `master`. But almost immediately `master` was reverted to it's original form (before merge) by the use of `revert`

```
git revert -n OLDER_COMMIT^..NEWER_COMMIT
```

So - we have two branches. which have **separate** content. How can i `merge` branches master and update together? so branch master holds combined result? Could you help me with this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you are having trouble merging `update` into `master`, since `update` was previously merged into `master`, and then had those changes reverted (and then committed and pushed). If that's the case, you need to revert the revert (and then if you have further changes in `update`, you can then merge those in normally thereafter).

Look in `git log`, find the commit which reverted the merge. Revert that specific commit within the `master` branch:

`git revert SHA1`